# weird *ngFor behavior

Tags: javascript, angular, svg, ngfor

i have a list with *ngFor

```
 <div class="items" *ngFor="let infection of missionData?.infections">
    <span class="name">{{infection.name}}, {{infection.state}}</span>
    <span class="device-status" *ngIf="infection.state">
      <app-svg-icon [name]="infection.state" [size]="18"></app-svg- 
         icon>
    </span>
```

everything works fine, but when a new infection is added to the list (through websocket) all the icons of the rest of the infections, change to be the same as the last one added even though i see the state is the same as it was.

this is my app-svg where i think the problem is :

```
import { Component, HostBinding, Input, OnChanges, OnInit, 
SimpleChange, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { IconService } from '@app/services';
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
selector: 'app-svg-icon',
template: ``,
styles: [`app-svg-icon {
display: inline-block;
 }`],
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class SvgIconComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  @HostBinding('innerHtml') inner;
  @Input() name: string;
  @Input() size: number;
  mobWidth: any;
  svgData = '';
  constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer, private iconService: IconService) {
    this.mobWidth = (window.screen.width);
   }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.name) {
      this.setSVG();
    }
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: { [key: string]: SimpleChange }) {
    for (const change in changes) {
      if (!changes[change].firstChange) {
        if (changes[change].previousValue !== changes[change].currentValue) {
          this[change] = changes[change].currentValue;
          if (change === 'name' || change === 'size') {
            this.setSVG();
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  private setSVG() {
    this.svgData = this.iconService.getIcon(this.name, this.size);
    this.inner = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.svgData);
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this a typo `this[change] = changes[change].currentValue;` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because on adding new infection ngOnChanges is triggered and that for in your function is calling setSVG for all infections, but setSVG is fetching same picture with getIcon because in this. name and size you have data from last infection.
You need to fix your ngOnChanges function. Use isFirstChange() method to check whether the new value is the first value assigned.

Comment: but i check for first change ... you can see

Comment: Yea but it's incorrect, use `if (!changes[change].isFirstChange()) {}` insted of .firstChange.
You are using property that is unset in constructor so it's always undefined and your if is always true, if you use method isFirstChange() it will check if it's first change or not

Comment: i changed it to what you said, still same

Comment: it doesnt even get to `this.setSvg()` in the `ngOnChanges` ... but still do that

Comment: Found out, it's because u are using same component for all pictures and your component have data, when new infection is added that data is changed and icon is same for all infections, because they are all referencing to component data. You need to save svg data in some variable for each infection and pass them to this component.

Comment: hey thanks, i don't understand how should i do it. can you try to explain how to solve this? because if you look at svg-icon.component i have a variable with the name svgData that does what you say, so maybe it is not the problem

Comment: Ah yea i saw that now, can you comment ngOnChanges and test your code to be sure that problem is there? If it's not working with commented that part of code then i can't see where is problem

Comment: yes even when the ngOnChanges is commented, the same thing happens

Comment: ok i solved this issue, it was due to the classes of the SVG was the same classes so they change the colors and it looked like it is the same infection.state. haha this is one hell of a bug to find xD

Comment: Haha yea, it's hard to find it. Congrats 